# Sending pushes to devices without google play account

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

We're developping an Android app which uses Parse. All devices that install the app have their deviceToken and pushType registered in _Installation Parse Table upon registration, since they have google play accounts. They all receive push notifications from Parse without any problems.

I have a fairphone device which has been used for testing purposes since the beginning. It has never had google play account, but Parse push notifications were succesfully received without problems. But some three months ago, this device doesn't get push notifications anymore. I have uninstalled the app completely, erased all data, given again permission to receive notifications, but nothing works.

I can't understand why this device doesn't get push notifications from Parse.

My question is: is there a way to debug my app and discover why a certain device doesn't get parse push notifications?

This is my manifest part related to parse push notifications:

```
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="br.org.eita.responsa.push.ResponsaPushReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="br.org.eita.responsa" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```